# Design pattern to address invitation race condition

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns

Before I begin describing the problem I'm facing, let me assure you that I've checked if there already is another thread where this has been talked about. After about 5-6 tries clicking on suggestions, I gave up, since it's hard to get an idea from threads with generic names like "What design pattern can I use?"

So I've given this question as descriptive a title as I could come up with. The reason for my concern about this being asked already is that it feels like it should be a fairly common problem (surely others would've encountered this in their client-server program).

=====

So here's my problem...

I've got a single server S, and several clients C1, C2, ..., Cn.
A client can do 1 of three things at any given time:

1. Create an event.
2. Invite other clients to created events.
3. Accept or reject invitations to events created by other clients.

A client sees names for events they've created (and possibly invited other clients to) as well as names for events they've accepted invitations to. The server processes all invitations; when a client invites another client to an event, the invitation goes through S but S knows nothing about an event E other than the name associated with it, the inviting client, and the invited clients. Let's symbolise the name of an event E as |E|.

Now for two events Ea and Eb, |Ea| != |Eb| does not imply Ea != Eb. That is, just because two events have different names does not mean they are different. I won't formally define what makes two events the same here, but as a use-case, let's say two events are the same if they have the same location/time. However the server never knows this info remember, only the clients do, but the clients may not communicate well enough beforehand with each other and so may choose different names to represent the same (intended) event.

My problem: I want to avoid a situation where a client Ca accepts an invitation from a client Cb to an event Eb, and Cb accepts an invitation from Ca to Ea, where Ea = Eb. This would lead to each client seeing both |Ea| and |Eb|, which actually represent the same event.

Question: How do I avoid the above? Is there a design pattern that can work on the server alone, client alone, or both server and client together? The solution can include dialogs/prompts for clients.

=====

A practical implementation for such a client-server setup could be discussion topics as events and employees as clients. Imagine a situation where Craig and Matt are colleagues who rarely see each other. They suddenly realise that their boss had asked them to look into why a recent software upgrade wasn't working for some of their customers. But neither knows the other person has been asked to look into the issue as well. So Craig creates the event 'Discuss recent upgrade', and Matt (who's done bit more research than Craig)  suspecting it to be an (ahem) Adobe issue, creates 'Investigate new Adobe add-on'. They both invite each other to these topics, and both being very polite, readily accept. Confusion ensues.

Answer (score 0):

How about the solution running core component @ server?
I am trying to map this problem with the standard scheduling problem, with a variation of informing the conflicting appointments and finding conflict logic.

Here server keeps the list of events(or appointments). When a request for a new event comes, a conflict check is made. If a conflict is found (may be location and time or even something else - abstract this with a strategy pattern). Server completely conceals the complexity with a simple facade pattern.

@Client side a conflict can be coded to have dialog getting the user feedback to create a new or use existing event.

The next key thing will be, what and how an event will be stored. Again this majorly depends on use case. If we are designing for an event with following data

```
Name, Date, Start time, Location, Organizer, Description
```

The storage @ server can be typical 'Outlook based calendar' way or 'list of events @ buckets of time'.

Comment: The storage at server cannot contain any more info than an event name, inviting client and invited clients, as I've described in the question. So a conflict check needs to have logic limited to this info only. The point of this setup is ease of use for clients...quickly create an event by typing a name and inviting other clients. Purpose, time, location, discussion topic, intention, etc, etc, are all in the client's head.

Comment: I am curious without some kind of coordination(with or without server), how will we know all the available events. Not all clients will receive invites for every event. For eg. how about a conflict check for an event created by someone, who didn't invite this guy?  If this case can be ignored, we can have the conflict check @ client side itself.

Comment: The server stores and has a history of all the events and associated invitations. Clients can only see names of events they've created and that they've accepted invitations to. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "how about a conflict check for an event created by someone, who didn't invite this guy?" Could you please elaborate?

Comment: consider a,b,c clients. a created event E1 invite b. Only, a and b has the data about E1.  Now, c wants to create that event E1 (may be with a different name). How the conflict check can be done @ c client side?

Comment: Well I don't know how any conflict checks can be done, that's what I'm trying to figure out. In the situation you describe, let's say c creates E2. a and b should see |E1| and |E2|, while c should only see |E2| as c wasn't invited initially to E1.

Comment: Furthermore, E1 would be 'owned' by A and would contain A and B (let's use capitals). E2 would be owned by C and would contain A, B, and C (assuming both A and B accept the invite from C).

Comment: As you have mentioned, it is definitely a use case you want to address. For such a system there can be 2 approaches 1 is having a centralised component (may be a server component) maintaining the logic to resolve all the component (as mentioned in the answer above).  Other would be a distributed approach, where we need to have a components running in every client ensuring no conflicts during creating of an event @ any client. Clients must co-ordinate with each other with some kind of heart-beat event, conflict-check event. There must be a specific component for cluster management.

Comment: Checks for conflicts have to be done on the server in this 'lazy' client design. But no invitation can be assured to conflict with another as intentions are not made available to the server. So the server has to notify clients whenever it suspects there might be a conflict. The question now becomes how and what is the order in which the server processes invitations? I.e, does it check for other invitations in its queue before acting on an invitation or just process them based on invitations it has already seen, etc.

Comment: And two invitations I1 and I2 can be suspected to conflict if the clients contained in it (including owner/creator) are exactly the same.

Comment: Whenever you said server has to inform clients about a possible conflict, is the role of server component is just a mediator or broker kind of thing or u want to build some intelligence there?

Comment: One more thing to consider is the  events can be created@ different times and any time ahead like months ago. So the order of processing @ server alone has no significance unless there is memory

Comment: There certainly is memory on the server. Every transaction going through the server will be recorded/stored. So in addition to mediator, it will also be  a record keeper. Conflicts will tend to happen when clients do stuff simultaneously or within very short time spaces. Once enough time has passed, clients will know that they already belong to an event and will therefore not create a duplicate one.